# WPF Binding not propagated

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have the following XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="#FFFFFFC7">
    <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="SkyBlue" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="50" >
        <view:CActionListView  DataContext="{Binding ActionViewModels.Inst}" />
    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Where the ScollViewer and the Border are binded with an object of type "CustoWorkOrder.MainObject"

As you can see in the following picture; the binding is correct; and the Border binded object has a property called "ActionViewModels.Inst" (and the list of this object contains 3 items)

[image: image example 1]

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k6V6.jpg) for enlarged image.

The object CActionListView is binded with a "TRACAWPFLib.ViewModel.CActionListViewModel"; but it's not the one of the border; it's a new instance. (See following picture)

[image: image example 2]

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCbFc.jpg) for enlarged image.

Does somebody  know why the binding is not propagated?

Comment: I have read and re-read your question several times and still have no idea what your question is. Please take some time to make your question clearer, so that we can attempt to answer it.

Comment: In fact, the datacontext is not relayed on the CActionListViewModel. I wait in the CActionListViewModel, the same context than in the border (in order to view the List of Actions); but like it's a new object; there is no action. For me it's not the awaited result.